# Why does my code skip over the return statement in the if statement and then execute the else statement body?

Tags: java, return

When I run my code with test case find("mississippi", "sip"), it prints out "sippi" and then "false" below. I was confused about this because I was under the assumption that "true" would be printed.

I've tried removing the return statement within the if body but get an error

```java
public static boolean find (String text, String str) //method to find "str" within "text"
    {
        if (text.substring(0, str.length()).equals(str))
        {
            System.out.println(text);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            text = text.substring(1);
            find(text, str);
            System.out.println(text);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I expect the output to be sippi true, but the actual output is sippi false

Answer (score 2):

You're not using the boolean returned by the recursive calls to `find(...)`, so your function currently always returns `false` if the first `if` evaluates to `false`. An additional base case is needed to return `false` when appropriate:

```java
public static boolean find (String text, String str) {
    if (text.length() < str.length()) { return false; }

    if (text.substring(0, str.length()).equals(str))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        text = text.substring(1);
        return find(text, str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Minor detail: one could add ```if (text.length() < str,length()) return false``` as the first line to avoid an index-out-of-bounds exception on too-short input.  The test on ```text.length() == 0``` could then be removed as redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You recursively work your way down until you get a match for "sip" and print out "sippi".  The innermost call then returns true.  That takes you out to the next level, after the call to find(), and there you print out "sippi" again.  This call then returns false.  That takes you out to the next level, after the call to find(), and there you print out "isippi".  This call then returns false... and so on.

I see nothing that prints "true" or "false".

This seems to be a common misunderstanding of recursion. People get the nested-call part, but not the nested-return.  Each return only exits the current level of call, not the entire call stack.